# Node pointer to current Node during mutile function call

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have declared a global pointer ptr and want that it should point to current node during different function call.

This is a sample code where I am creating a new node in fun1 and inserting in link list. In func2 I want to update the other members of newNode in linklist with a different value.

Currently I am traversing the link list to get the current Node or last Node which I dont want since during insertion of new Records already we have to traverse to reach to last Node thus storing the address of last Node.

But by doing the below I am not getting the proper values. Kindly someone suggest where I went wrong.

I am doing like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int data1;
    int data2;
    struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head=NULL;
struct Node* ptr =NULL;                    /* Global pointer  */
void insertNode(struct Node ** , struct Node* );
void fun1();
void fun2();


void fun1()
{  
    struct Node* ptr1 =NULL;
    ptr1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
    ptr1->data1=1; /* intilaizing with some values */
    insertNode(&head,ptr1);
}

void fun2()
{
    /* Updating the current Node in the linklist with new value . */ 
    ptr->data2=2;

}

void insertNode(struct Node ** head, struct Node* NewRec)
{

if(*head ==NULL ) 
{
    NewRec->next = *head;
   *head = NewRec;
    ptr=*head;
}
else
{
/* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
    struct Node* current=NULL;
    current = *head;
    while (current->next!=NULL )
    {
        current = current->next;
    }
    NewRec->next = current->next;
    current->next = NewRec;
    ptr=current->next;

    }
}
int main ()
{
    fun1();
    fun2();
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", head->data1);
        printf("%d",head->data2);
        head=head->next;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a classic mistake.

This is wrong:

```
ptr1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node*));
```

The allocated space here is `sizeof(struct Node*)` which is the size of a pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes depending on the platform). But you need to allocate space for the whole `struct Node` structure, whose size is `sizeof(struct Node)`.

So you simply need this:

```
ptr1 = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

BTW: in C you don't cast the return value of `malloc` so you actually should write this:

```
ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Comment: Thanks Michael for your valuable suggestion

Comment: Fix my problem with the asnwer from Micheal